# Image Breaking on the right hand Side

Tags: css

The "Bill me Later" image is breaking on the right hand side of [this page](http://www.espnshop.com/helpdesk/index.jsp?display=payment&subdisplay=process).
How can I fix this to look right?

Comment: This question has no value to future visitors. Include the broken code and description of the problem.

Comment: to View the Code go to the Link.

Comment: I get that, thanks. The problem is that the content at that link is not static. If I visit this page again in a year, the code will be different. Consider using jsFiddle as a permanent code source.

Comment: now check my answer and let me know if i am lagging somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you you giving smaller width to the ifram

here is your solution see the editing in the circle

1 .you can do this
[image]

**2**. or you can do this

[image]

both will work

and the result is bellow and sorry for the first circle its done by mistake

[image]

Comment: add Width to table border does not effect anything.

Comment: Issue is Fixed. thanks all for your Help :-)

Comment: @user1515669 i am very great full to help you sir